# What is the API Equivalent for setClipToOutline for API lower than Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I have a MapView that I would like to clip to a circle drawable.
MapView:

```
        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">
        </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>
```

And here is the the circle drawable:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke android:color="#ffffff" android:width="100dp"></stroke>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

So with Lollipop, I can simply do a

```
mapView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);
mapView.setClipToOutline(true);
```

Which clips the View into a circle. But this doesn't work below API 21. What is the equivalent way to do it with the support library for Jellybean and KitKat?

Comment: did you found any solution?